# AutoWiring steps with Spring Cucumber Serenity

Tags: java, spring, testing, cucumber-jvm, serenity-bdd

I'm failing miserably to auto wire some steps.
To illustrate the point, I made a small sample project on github

https://github.com/lpicquet/serenity-cucumber-spring

I am trying to autowire steps so that I can share data between them but the test is currently failing. Anyone can help?

Comment: Can you post the relevant code within the question, and not some external link? Please also see [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are using a different Runner. Generally people use the `SpringRunner.class` which handles the ability to create the test context etc.

> Construct a new SpringRunner and initialize a TestContextManager to provide Spring testing functionality to standard JUnit 4 tests.

To use a different runner along with spring functionality you can use a combination of a `ClassRule` and a `Rule`

```
@ClassRule
public static final SpringClassRule SPRING_CLASS_RULE = new SpringClassRule();

@Rule
public final SpringMethodRule springMethodRule = new SpringMethodRule();
```

> SpringClassRule is a custom JUnit TestRule that supports class-level features of the Spring TestContext Framework in standard JUnit tests by means of the TestContextManager and associated support classes and annotations.
>
> In contrast to the SpringJUnit4ClassRunner, Spring's rule-based JUnit support has the advantage that it is independent of any Runner and can therefore be combined with existing alternative runners like JUnit's Parameterized or third-party runners such as the MockitoJUnitRunner.
>
> In order to achieve the same functionality as the SpringJUnit4ClassRunner, however, a SpringClassRule must be combined with a SpringMethodRule, since SpringClassRule only supports the class-level features of the SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.

Without these there is no ability to Autowire within your dependant classes etc.

I've added a PR to your project with passing tests.

Comment: The cucumber-spring integration creates `TestContextManager`. So I don't think the class rules are needed or actually do anything.

Comment: Has this worked for anyone? I can see the answer marked but no upvotes.  I've been struggling with the same issue: getting Serenity-Cucumber-Spring to work toghether.

Comment: So basically with 7.15.0 version of io.cucumber, was using cucumber-spring dependency which was causing the issue for me. When changed to serenity-cucumber dependency injection worked. Thanks !!!